# Is istinja part of wudu?

Tags: salat, wudu

I am confused if istinja is part of wudu because one has to perform wudu before performing salah but does this mean they have to perform istinja too?

When I search online on how to do wudu, look in some books or even Islamic shows on the TV that show how to do wudu, they do not include istinja as a step. Also at college when people pray they do not perform istinja, but does that mean their salah is invalid as they are not in a complete state of purity?

My questions:

1) Is istinja part of wudu

2) Does one have to perform istinja before salah?

Please include where you got the information from e.g. quote hadith.

(According to Sunni Hanafi Madhab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There are just 7 things which invalidate wodhu:

Passing of urine. 
Excretion. 
Passing wind from the rear. 
A sleep, deep enough to restrict sight and hearing.
Things on account of which a person loses his sensibility, like insanity, intoxication or unconsciousness. 
Istihaza . 
Janabat,

as you can see, being in the state of Nijasah (impurity) is not something that invalidates wudhu. passing urine will invalidate wodhu not the urine itself. your body may get Najis after performing wodhu (for instance, by getting a blood stain on your body) but it has nothing to do with your wodhu.

2. There are two kinds of purity which are completely different from each other :

1)purity from Khabas "خبث" which means getting rid of urine, blood etc by using one of purifiers (Mutahharat)

2)purity from Hdas "حدث" which means performing wodhu or ghusl after occurring one of the 7 things mentioned above

3. The condition under which Salat is valid is purity both from "حدث" and "خبث".

as a result one can perform wodhu after passing urine and before Istinja, but he or she has to do Istinja for performing Salat.

Comment: i had heard that some little amount of najs is allowed