# Is tissue paper sufficient for the toilet?

Tags: salat, taharah

If you are used to using water and tissue to clean it is very hard to use only tissue and feel clean. However it would depend on how solid is your output as more solidity would be less need for water generally speaking.

Now salah cannot be missed because you just used tissue say in a non Muslim place of work and you didn't arrange to have a bottle or wet tissue.

Question: So in this situation would you try your best to clean only with tissue but it didn't do a great job as your output was softer but that is best you can do and then you do wudhu and pray??

Having said that if you can use water to do wudhu and after washing your hands you ought to be able to use it for cleaning after toilet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is istinja' necessary for ablution?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30920/is-istinja-necessary-for-ablution)

Answer (score 1):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions

Istinja is not part of the wudhu now if someone has just used tissue paper to clean after using toilet and wants to perform Salah so his Salah would be valid but with some conditions,

*Making sure he has cleaned properly and if the najasat or impurity is equal to one dirham then his prayer would be valid but he has to redo his prayer , If the najasat is less than one dirham then ,His prayer would be valid he doesnt need to redo his prayer and if the najasat is more than one dirham then it is compulsory for him to get rid of that impurity,His prayer would not be valid in such state.*

(To identify size of the one dirham our fuqaha have explained to pour water in our palms of hand the remaining water in the palm is considered to be the size of the one dirham)

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.