# Is tissue paper enough to clean after urinating according to four madhabs?

Tags: sunni, najis

Is tissue paper enough to clean after urinating according to four madhabs?  What is the consensus of the present scholars?  I'm seeking a broad answer to this question.

Comment: I wanted to know that is it okay to wet the tissue with water and clean the private part after urinating?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is istinja' necessary for ablution?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30920/is-istinja-necessary-for-ablution)

Comment: What is views of the madhabs regarding this and again if I have ample scope to clean by water and still that if I use tissue paper will it be sufficient?

Comment: @Ali_Waris Our scholars mentioned to avoid cleaning by making tissue wet as it could spread the filth.

Comment: @Faqirah I don't mean just using the wet tissue, but cleaning with a wet tissue first, and then cleaning with a dry one to remove water droplets.

Comment: @Ali_Waris see this http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2014/05/11/9446/

Comment: @Faqirah I guess the 'filth'  that they are talking about is faeces/stool/excreta and not the urine because I don't see it practical that using tissue paper will spread urine, instead it will absorb the droplets.

Answer (score 1):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions,

As you have asked that if tissue paper would be sufficient to clean after urinating so our scholars have mentioned that sunnah would be fulfilled by wiping the area using the tissue paper because sunnah is to remove najasat from private parts but still doubts could be left on a mind regarding taharah so sunnah would be fulfilled but need to make sure that taharah or cleanliness is acheived,But when both are present then it is better to choose water to clean the area.

See [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36174/is-tissue-paper-sufficient-for-the-toilet) and [this](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2011/10/18/what-is-the-best-way-to-clean-oneself-after-using-the-toilet/).

Allah swt and his Messenger knows best.