# Praying when in doubt about clothes

Tags: salat, practical-islam, taharah, najis

I travel a lot and sometimes I run out of clothes and I forget if my clothes are clean or due to some intimacy between my spouse and many times **I have to use toilet roll as working in office or outside**. What is a way around or Quran say about someone who cannot control nature call and in travelling and using a tissue roll, as I miss a lot of salat because of it?

**Are my clothes still ok to pray as I had to use toilet and absence of water forced me to use tissue roll and what When I arrive at home and use water to clean myself but same clothing**?

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Please do not use comments to answer questions or to debate controversial points. They are intended for seeking clarification and for constructive criticism of the post itself.

Comment: Your question is already answered here https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30920/is-istinja-necessary-for-ablution/30953#30953 so it is a duplicate if you can't make out what lacks in that post!

Answer (score 1):

Your Salat is correct unless you remember that it was certainly not clean after a while...