# Is my wudu valid if I saw something nasty?

Tags: salat, wudu

I was praying isha, after which and going for tahajjud (night prayer) while I checked my mobile for my mother messaged but instagram was open after unlocking my mobile and there was something nasty (nude) photo came to the feed. Is my wudu broken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The things that invalidate wudu' (abltuion) are:

1. Any discharge from the front or back passage.
2. Emission of urine or stools from anywhere other than the urethra or anus.
3. Losing one’s mind as an insanity or by losing it temporarily for a certain length of time for some reason such as sleep, unconsciousness, intoxication, etc.
4. Touching one’s private parts (see for example in [al-Muwatta'](https://sunnah.com/urn/500900))
5. Eating camel meat (see for example in [sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/3/123))
6. Apostasy.

So none of them include looking at nudity, that's why it doesn't break your wudu'. However looking at nudity considered a sin if one does it with intention. Also read [this fatwa](http://www.islamweb.net/en/article/162737/does-seeing-others-awrah-invalidate-ones-ablution) on your topic and [this](https://islamqa.info/en/14321) on the topic of changing clothes which shows a list of things that invalidate wudu'

Comment: Are clothes are considered clean if u use tissue to clean feces and doing wudu afterwards?

Comment: @Nofel here's an answer for that issue http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30920/is-istinja-necessary-for-ablution

Comment: @Nofel that's a different question and Medi1 linked at a possible duplicate!

Answer (score 0):

no, your wudu did not broken. wudu will broken if yo touch your genital part, or you touch non mahram woman(not your inner family) or non mahram man(not your inner family). this is applied if you follow the sect sunni Shafi'i.. Wallahua'lam bissawab..

Answer (score -1):

Actually. It can break wudu. These things are taken from sahih Hadith. But if we take theoretically "Wudu is process in which it cleans the heart sins weight and clean our body both chemically and physically." So if after watching that photo you feel corrupted or mind attract a little bit towards that or you think it in brain repeatedly so Wudu will be accepted but Wudu will not be proper and Allah surely don't like bad intention.
In last Allah knows best.