# Is there a condition to use only toilet tissue for cleaning?

Tags: practical-islam, wudu, taharah, najis

The ahadith mention using water or a minimum of 3 stones (stones=toilet tissue today) and the number should be odd. Scholars state both can be used together even though there is no Hadith where both were used in one instance.

My question is you can tell when you wipe how much water will be required (little or lots) but even in cases where the tissue comes back "clean" there is *still* residue. So what is the context of this Hadith which states that the Prophet صلى الله عليه وسلم said that 3 stones (3 wipes of tissue?) will be enough? Was water in limited supply? Was it too cold to use water? Was water not available?

I'm referring to these two ahadith:

> [Narrated Aisha, Ummul Mu'minin:](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/1/40)
>   The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: When any of you goes to relieve himself, he should take with him three stones to cleanse himself, for they will be enough for him.
>   حَدَّثَنَا سَعِيدُ بْنُ مَنْصُورٍ، وَقُتَيْبَةُ بْنُ سَعِيدٍ، قَالاَ حَدَّثَنَا يَعْقُوبُ بْنُ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ، عَنْ أَبِي حَازِمٍ، عَنْ مُسْلِمِ بْنِ قُرْطٍ، عَنْ عُرْوَةَ، عَنْ عَائِشَةَ، أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ "‏ إِذَا ذَهَبَ أَحَدُكُمْ إِلَى الْغَائِطِ فَلْيَذْهَبْ مَعَهُ بِثَلاَثَةِ أَحْجَارٍ يَسْتَطِيبُ بِهِنَّ فَإِنَّهَا تُجْزِئُ عَنْهُ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>   Grade   : Hasan (Al-Albani)   حسن   (الألباني)  حكم
>
> [Narrated Khuzaymah ibn Thabit:](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/1/41)
>   The Prophet (ﷺ) was asked about cleansing (after relieving oneself). He said: (One should cleanse oneself) with three stones which should be free from dung.
>   Abu Dawud said: A similar tradition has been narrated by Abu Usamah and Ibn Numair from Hisham.
>   حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ مُحَمَّدٍ النُّفَيْلِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو مُعَاوِيَةَ، عَنْ هِشَامِ بْنِ عُرْوَةَ، عَنْ عَمْرِو بْنِ خُزَيْمَةَ، عَنْ عُمَارَةَ بْنِ خُزَيْمَةَ، عَنْ خُزَيْمَةَ بْنِ ثَابِتٍ، قَالَ سُئِلَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم عَنْ الاِسْتِطَابَةِ فَقَالَ ‏ "‏ بِثَلاَثَةِ أَحْجَارٍ لَيْسَ فِيهَا رَجِيعٌ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ قَالَ أَبُو دَاوُدَ كَذَا رَوَاهُ أَبُو أُسَامَةَ وَابْنُ نُمَيْرٍ عَنْ هِشَامٍ يَعْنِي ابْنَ عُرْوَةَ ‏.‏
>   Grade   : Sahih (Al-Albani)   (صحيح   (الألباني

Comment: This seems to me relevant https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30920/is-istinja-necessary-for-ablution

Answer (score -1):

Why is that relevant? One should be doing istinjaa or istijmar or ideally both whenever going to the toilet so why the need to do it before wudhu if you don't need to go to the toilet? If the front and back private area is clean no need to clean especially prior to wudhu.