# Is it necessary to use toilet paper after using the water?

Tags: practical-islam

Is it important to use tissue paper after the using of water.

Comment: I'd say this is covered in my answer on [Is istinja' necessary for ablution?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30920/is-istinja-necessary-for-ablution).

Comment: It's also closely related to [Is there a condition to use only toilet tissue for cleaning?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/45129/17163)

Answer (score 0):

It's advisable (but not compulsory) for at least 2 reasons: (1) you can check you are clean if the (white) tissue comes back white else you need to use more water; (2) you will be dry otherwise you will sit on a damp behind and it can lead to fungal infection of that area. If you are living in a hot country then you may get dry naturally outside however. You can use a hairdryer to dry as well.

Answer (score -1):

The use of paper towels is not mandatory, it has been clean after cleaning with water, like the last brother said,  "Using paper towels can check whether it is clean", at the same time, it is dry after using paper towels and will not produce bacteria.