# What is Tayamum and when is it applicable?

Tags: wudu, tayammum

I am a returning Muslim and live in Europe. As day time all namaz happen and I have confusion over how to perform namaz. As I use toilet in office with toilet role and I don’t know any other way to do wudu as there is no places in offices In Europe. 
I heard about tayamum, (dried wudu). Is it something I can do in my case? 
My namaz are missed in the confusion of using toilet roll after passing feces and having a weak bladder which keep dripping. 
How can I not miss my prayers!?

Comment: Is there water available anywhere? I am sure there will be. You can just do wudu. All you need is water to do wudhu. If there's no wudhu stalls then you can just get water from the sink and perform wudhu. Tayamum is if there's is no water available for a long distance, then you may use earth dirt.

Comment: @Armaan yes but not space for wudu. There is sink which purity isn’t sure.

Comment: You do not need a space for wudu, I've one seen someone fill up a glass of water and then used that water to perform wudhu and he barely used a lot of water so it saved quite a lot of water.

Comment: You should specify whether you want to know what is tayamum or whether you are -only- interested whether it is applicable for your case. In any case you should try to explain why you think you are even allowed to perform tayamum. Note that if water is available tayamum is not allowed (unless you have a legal excuse: like fearing death if you use water, so you need to explain)! Also note that you may pray even if you didn't do istinja' with water https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30920/is-istinja-necessary-for-ablution/30953#30953

Answer (score 1):

**What is Tayamum  or How to perform Tayammum ?**

There are three obligatory elements in tayammum:

1. Making intention (niyyah),
2. Rubbing the palms of both hands on clean soil and wiping the entire face thoroughly with them,
3. Striking the hands on clean soil and wiping the right arm first and then the left one.

**The chief conditions under which tayammum become permissible are as follows:**

1. When one is unable to find clean water to perform wudu' or ghusl (it is always fard [obligatory] to search for water when one is in a city),
2. When one is afflicted with a disease that prevents one from using water or when there is the danger that one would die or fall sick because of cold if one used water,
3. When near water is an enemy, a wild or poisonous animal that will set upon,
4. When one cannot use water because one is imprisoned,
5. When one is threatened with death,
6. When a traveler does not have extra water other than that which he will drink,
7. When, though there is a well, it is not possible to extract water from it.
8. This situation, for any salah that you can not perform alone. Example as if you go for wudu for janazah salah, It will be late, you can not join janazah salah,