# Dried clean cloth kept mess with dry unclean cloth

Tags: taharah, clothing

I took the clean clothes & gone for the shower after I have found impurity in the night, but I forgot to separate them from the uncleaned one, and there was no wetness in uncleaned one.

So is that clean cloth still clean and for praying?

Or

I need another clean cloth?

Comment: You only have 2 sets of clothes??? :P  Why worry yourself over such a question when you can simply get a 3rd set. Why complicate life lol :D

Answer (score 1):

If the impurity is dry, then it does not pass to the one that touches it. So you don't need another clean cloth. You just separate the clean clothes and shake once to remove any doubt.

Below is a [Sahih Hadith from Sahih Muslim, Book 2, Hadith 566](https://sunnah.com/muslim/2/134)

> 'Alqama and Aswad reported:
>   A person stayed in the house of A'isha and in the morning began to wash his garment. A'isha said: In case you saw it (i. e. drop of semen), it would have served the purpose (of purifying the garment) if you had simply washed that spot; and in case you did not see it, it would have been enough to sprinkle water around it, for when I saw that (semem) on the garment of the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ), I simply scraped it off and he offered prayer, while putting that on.`

See also - https://islamqa.info/en/111904

Comment: And also what is the rule for I by mistakenly wore the cloth that was dried but unclean over the garment which I which I already had wore. But as soon as I got that, I removed my undergarment off of it. Ex: unclean pant over clean undergarment

Comment: @ShoaibQuraishi I think this is covered here [Is istinja' necessary for ablution?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30920/is-istinja-necessary-for-ablution/30953#30953)